# How can I store user data (shared preferences) in this code?

Tags: java, android, facebook

My Mainpage is the facebook-login activity and will proceed to navigation drawer.Everything works fine but I need to LogIn every time I open the app. Ive tried to do sharedpreferences and accesstoken. I dont know how to do it with this code. Pls hlp me.

This is my Main.java

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {
CallbackManager callbackManager;
LoginButton loginButton; //facebookLoginButton


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    assert loginButton != null;
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult login_result) {

            getUserInfo(login_result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {

        }
    });
}

protected void getUserInfo(LoginResult login_result){

    GraphRequest data_request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            login_result.getAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(
                        JSONObject json_object,
                        GraphResponse response) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this,HomeActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("jsondata",json_object.toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
    Bundle parameter = new Bundle();
    parameter.putString("fields", "id,name,email,picture.width(150).height(150)");
    data_request.setParameters(parameter);
    data_request.executeAsync();

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.e("data", data.toString());
}

 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}
}
```

Help pls.

Comment: http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/arraylist-in-sharedpreferences/ follow the tutorial  !!

Comment: you can search it in other questions insead of asking a fresh question. there are so many results for this query on stackoverflow aswell as on google

Answer (score 4):

Initialize Variable

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
```

on your OnCreate()

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Save Your Data

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("name", name);
        editor.putString("phone", phone);
        editor.commit();
```

get Shared Preferences saved data

```
SharedPreferences settins = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Youractivity.this);
     String pref1=settings.getString("name", "anon");
     String pref2=settings.getString("Phone", "anon");
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually Facebook SDK stores everything you need. For example you can check if the user has logged in by checking access token for `null`. `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()` returns `null` if the user is not logged in. And you don't need to store profile info, SDK already does it, for example by calling `Profile.getCurrentProfile()` you retrieve some basic information about currently logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to name the Shared Preferences while saving and accessing. This is helpful in case of multiple Shared Preferences.

On the activity where you are saving, type:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref1", MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = pref.edit(); 
editor.putString("firstName",firstName);
editor.commit();
```

On the activity where you are accessing, type:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 String firstName = prefs.getString("firstName", "null");
```